# Real time authorization to user based on external factor in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I need to implement a way where I can give certain privileges to the user "by the second" and without needing to reloading the page depending if he's still active by a third-party api.

I can't rely solely on javascript ajax for this since it would be easy to overcome.

Is there any solution already on Rails to handle authorization like this? I think it would be similar to DRM or any kind of PPM apps.

Comment: Why can't you rely on ajax calls? Each call can still check whether the user is authenticated and simply return a 401 instead of content if he/she is not authorized.

Comment: If the user disable javascript how can I still check if the user is still there?

Comment: I should log out the user immediately if he is not "active" anymore by this third-party API.